# Issue with php search results

Tags: php, magento

I have the following search form:

```
<form action="/playsearch" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="imported" id="imported" class="">
<label class="" for="imported">Imported</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="fresh" id="fresh" class="">
<label class="" for="fresh">Fresh</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="labeled" id="labeled" class="">
<label for="labeled" class="">Labeled</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="wrapped" id="wrapped" class="">
<label for="wrapped" class="">Wrapped</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="organic" id="organic" class="">
<label for="organic" class="">Organic</label><br>
<button type="submit" name="fruitsearch">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In playsearch page i have this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['imported']) && $_POST['imported'] == 1){$qImported = 'Yes';}
if(isset($_POST['fresh']) && $_POST['fresh'] == 1){$qFresh = 'Yes';}
if(isset($_POST['labeled']) && $_POST['labeled'] == 1){$qLabeled = 'Yes';}
if(isset($_POST['wrapped']) && $_POST['wrapped'] == 1){$qWrapped = 'Yes';}
if(isset($_POST['organic']) && $_POST['organic'] == 1){$qOrganic = 'Yes';}

if (isset($_POST['fruitsearch'])) { $fruitsearch= $_POST['fruitsearch']; }

if (isset($fruitsearch)) {
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $readresult = $write->query("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM catalog_category_product ORDER BY product_id");
    while ($row = $readresult->fetch() ) {
        $prodid = explode(" ", $row['product_id']);
        foreach ($prodid as $id){
            $_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
            $_product->load($id);
            $attributeSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();
            if($attributeSetName == 'Fruits'){
                $attribute_imported = $_product->getAttributeText('is_imported');
                $attribute_fresh = $_product->getAttributeText('is_fresh');
                $attribute_labeled = $_product->getAttributeText('is_labeled');
                $attribute_wrapped = $_product->getAttributeText('is_wrapped');
                $attribute_organic = $_product->getAttributeText('is_organic');

                if($qImported == $attribute_imported && $qFresh == $attribute_fresh && $qLabeled == $attribute_labeled && $qWrapped == $attribute_wrapped && $qOrganic == $attribute_organic){
                    echo $name.'<br/>';
                }
            }
    }  

  } 
}
?>
```

A product can have each or a combination of those 5 filters (imported, fresh, labeled, wrapped, organic). My issue is that if, for example, when i click imported and wrapped in search form, i get only the "imported" ones, and i know there are products "imported" and "wrapped". How my query should look to have the right results for any combination?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: 1. don't store `Yes/No` in db, but `0/1`; 2. that `explode()` in order to get ids is smell for unnormalized database - I advise you to learn about `JOIN` operations.

Comment: the platform is Magento and all those 5 attributes ($attribute_imported and so) have a "Yes/No"  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the post attributes are set, write SQL code to check whether the condition is met. This will be used later in your joins.
2. Do not query all your products. Write a single query which joins `product` with `entity_attribute_set`. Use a where clause where you include the conditions generated in step 1.
3. Iterate through your results and display the result.

You are sending a lot of queries to your database server. Reduce their number by sending a single query. You are retrieving many unnecessary records. Filter them out. In your query in the where conditions use the `or` operation on the conditions generated in step 1.

Comment: Also, your PHP variables are only getting set if the checkbox is checked. Better to do this: `$qImported = (isset($_POST['imported']) && $_POST['imported'] == 1) ? 'Yes': 'No';` so that they will be set either way.

Comment: Nice one, @Revent, I forgot to add that to the answer. You are absolutely right.